# Thymeleaf - Loop values into textarea

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've been stack with a problem in [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/), that is, looping values into a *textarea*. My controller provides me with a list/collection via the model binding:

```
model.addAttribute("response", getDefectMessage.getMessage());
```

*getDefectMessage.getMessage()* returns the following (please see image below), in which I only need description in this case.

[image]

In my HTML, I am able to display the index and count of the provided data retrieved from the model (please see sample code below).

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="res, stat : *{response}">
        <td th:text="${stat.count}" />
        <td>
            <textarea type="text" th:text="${res[__${stat.index}__].description}"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Having said that, I get a *SpringEL expression exception* when rendering (please see image below).

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "res[0].description" (defect_details:24)
```

**Been a newbie in Thymeleaf, may I please get assistance in how I can go about displaying values from a list into a textarea. (Thanks in advance).**

Comment: @Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai, please see update above with image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `res` represents a `DefectDto`. So you access it fields like `res.defectDescription`

```
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="res, stat : *{response}">
          <td th:text="${stat.count}" />
          <td>
              <textarea type="text" th:text="${res.defectDescription}"> 
              </textarea>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

- Or if `DefectDto` has a method `getDescription()` then you can do

```
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="res, stat : *{response}">
          <td th:text="${stat.count}" />
          <td>
              <textarea type="text" th:text="${res.description}"> 
              </textarea>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Stupid me!!! I must be exhausted. I should be calling defectDescription...